# Reduce indent in description in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, indentation, description

In `beamer`, text in `description` `items` is over-indented:

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}
  \begin{description}
  \item[FooBarBazZot] - foo bar \\ baz zot
  \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

places `bar` under `Zot` in `FooBarBazZot`:

[image]

How do I place `baz` under, say, `Bar` in `FooBarBazZot`? (like it is placed in the, say, `amsart` et al).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can modify the indention with `\setbeamersize{description width=0.57cm}`, just play around to whatever value you need.

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{description width=0.57cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}
  \begin{description}
  \item[FooBarBazZot] - foo bar \\ baz zot
  \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]